# How to consider where condition inside the query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query.

```
select student, case when student_color is '***' then 0 else 1 end
from student_table
where student_color = 'red'
```

I want to consider the student_color in case by where condition.
How can I achieve the case statement to be be prepared from where condition?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Comment: I'm not able to show the exact representation in the reply ALEX.
I want all the results separating with 0 and 1 when where condition satisfies..

Comment: Hello TOB I have added where for understanding purpose....
I don't want the data to be filtered.. I want the data to be separated with the clause provided.

Comment: You should have read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Answer (score 1):

Where clause only filters the records. If you use where clause you will never get any other color. Case will take care of giving you the value either ) or 1. I think you might need below -

```
select student
      ,case when student_color = 'red' then 0 else 1 end as colour
from student_table
```

Comment: This should be `student_color = 'red'`, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Query with below

```
select student, 
    case 
    when student_color = 'red' 
    then 0 else 1 end
    from student_table
    where student_color = 'red'
```